# Convertir un valor entero a formato hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta para obtener en formato hh:mm:ss la resta de dos fechas en minutos, utilizando el formato de fecha de conversión 108 pero el resultado de la consulta lo da en minutos solamente

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal en la consulta?

```
Select CONVERT(varchar,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2020-08-25 06:03:23', GETDATE())),108) as [HH:MM:SS]
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se debe mostrar cuando la diferencia es mayor a un día?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` es una función que entrega un entero....luego estás tomando ese entero y convirtiendo a varchar. El formato 108 es para tipos de datos de fecha/hora, no para enteros

Comment: Esto resuelve tu pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizá haya mejores formas de hacerlo pero se me ocurre hacerlo así:

```
DECLARE @DESDE DATETIME, @HASTA DATETIME
SET @DESDE = CONVERT(DATETIME,'25/08/2020 06:03:23',103)
SET @HASTA = GETDATE()

SELECT CONCAT(DATEDIFF(SS,@DESDE, @HASTA)/60/60,':',(DATEDIFF(SS,@DESDE, @HASTA)/60)-((DATEDIFF(SS,@DESDE, @HASTA)/60/60)*60),':',DATEDIFF(SS,@DESDE,@HASTA)%60) AS [HH:MI:SS]
```

Aquí un ejemplo funcional:

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f06016546935a4955c886fb5211b8516)</kbd>

Solamente uso las variable `@DESDE` y `@HASTA` para efectos del ejemplo, no es necesario al aplicarlo, tampoco el tipo de fecha `DD/MM/YYYY` es necesario, solo me gusta personalmente manejar las fechas de esa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Para expresarlo en formato `HH:MM:SS`, debes convertir el número de segundos de regreso a un tipo fecha/hora antes de aplicar el convert final a `varchar` en formato `108` (hh:mm:ss).

Esto lo puedes lograr sumando la cantidad de segundos a cualquier fecha a la media noche, por ejemplo, al *epoch*:

```
select convert(varchar, dateadd(second, datediff(second, '2020-08-25 06:03:23', GETDATE()), 0), 108) as [HH:MM:SS]
```

Lo cual da como resultado:

```
HH:MM:SS
------------------------------
08:25:40

(1 row affected)


Completion time: 2020-08-26T14:29:03.1484996-06:00
```