# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un resultado a formato de tipo horas?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

```
SELECT * FROM PAGOS

CASE WHEN IdPago = 10

THEN PagoSemanal - DeudaSemanal

END AS TotalPago
```

Lo que quisiera de resultado es que `TotalPago` fuera en tipo horas, ejemplo si el resultado de la resta fuera 1200 entonces yo quisiera que resultara tipo así  12:00

No sé si se pueda convertir, yo no lo he podido hacer, si alguien supiera cómo, sería de gran ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: No se si haya solo de horas, pero aquí te dejo un buen ejemplo. Suerte

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384999/convertir-un-valor-entero-a-formato-hhmmss#:~:text=Para%20expresarlo%20en%20formato%20HH,hh%3Amm%3Ass).

Comment: Muchas gracias (Y)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir un valor entero a formato hh:mm:ss](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384999/convertir-un-valor-entero-a-formato-hhmmss)